# finding the volume below the part of the plane which is above the xy-plane

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

My function is $f(x,y) = 2-|x|-|y|$ and I'm supposed to find the volume below the part of the plane which is above the $xy$-plane.

I don't understand how to find the limits of my integrals for this problem. 
I have tried to draw the lines for all the cases for which the absolute value of $x$ and $y$ is both positive and negative, but I don't see the limits. Is there anyone who has any suggestions?

Comment: You don't have there a plane but in fact *four* planes: $\;2\pm x\pm y\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

For example, let us take the planes

$$\begin{cases}z=2-x-y\\z=2-x+y\end{cases}\implies y=0=\;\text{the $\;xz\,-$ plane} $$

Thus, projecting on the $\;xy\,-$ plane, we get

$$\begin{cases}y=2-x\\y=-2+x\end{cases}\implies 2x=4\implies x=2\,,\,y=0$$

Observe that for the whole four planes, you get as projection a square on the $\;xy\,-$ plane with vertices $\;(2,0),(-2,0)\;$ and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. The graph of this function is not a plane. However, this graph is symmetric with respect to the plane $x=0$ ($f(x,y)=f(x,-y)$) and the plane $y=0$ ($f(x,y)=f(-x,y)$). Hence it suffices to consider the case where $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$ and multiply the result by $4$:
$$V=4\int_{\{x\geq0, y\geq 0, x+y\leq 2\}}(2-x-y)\,dxdy
=4\int_{x=0}^2\left(\int_{y=0}^{2-x}(2-x-y)\,dy\right)\,dx.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: why should i multiply the result by 4 and are the limits a function of x and y or real numbers?

Comment: @i.ul Because you have the same volume also over the other quadrants. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2-abs(x)-abs(y),+x%3D-2..2,+y%3D-2..2

Comment: i still don´t see what my limits are

Comment: @i.ul Check the limits in my edited answer.